# Problem in sql query

Tags: sql

I have two tables called `customer` and `items`.

With single query I want to get all the `custid` and `customername` whose `custid='Custid1'` and `itemid` whose `custid='Custid1'`.

How can I build this query?? `custid` is the primary key of `customer` table. `custid` is the foreign key of `items` table.

I have written this query its not listing all the `custid`, only listing `custid` thrice... Here is my query:

```
create procedure spGetCustomer
as
begin
  select a.custid, a.custname,b.itemid  
  from customer a inner join items b on a.custid = b.custid 
  WHERE b.custid='custid1'
end
```

Comment: You keep alternating between `customerid` and `custid`.  Are those two different columns?  Or are you using two different names just to confuse us?  Also, please explain the difference between the output you want and the actual output you get.  Posting some sample data would be helpful too.

Comment: thats speling mistake column is custid only.

Comment: Your query looks okay - does it list the right set of data when executed stand-alone in SSMS ?? Or do you maybe have customers without "items"? In that case, you'd need a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear - what is it you really want??

The JOIN you have will list all customers with items where the `customer.custid` is `custid1`. But that doesn't seem to be what you're looking for.....

Could it be you're looking for all customers - with or without items - that have a specific `custid`?? Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    c.custid, c.custname, i.itemid  
FROM 
    dbo.customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.items i ON c.custid = i.custid 
WHERE 
    c.custid = 'custid1'
```

If the `items.custid` is indeed a foreign key into the `customer` table, there shouldn't be any items around that have `custid = custid1` that aren't joined to an existing customer.

Answer (score 0):

If your question actually relates to how you pass the parameter in, your proc should be:

create procedure spGetCustomer(@custid1 varchar(100))
as
begin
  select a.custid, a.custname,b.itemid
  from customer a inner join items b on a.custid = b.custid 
  WHERE b.custid=@custid1
end